# XML C# XPath - Network Packets

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, packet, packets

I am currently working on trying to packet filter using XML C# and XPath. The aim is to draw out each unique IP source address and see what IP destinations it has been talking to.

The aim is to view, using a form, the Source and a list of the Destinations either using a list box or property grid.

```
public void LoadPackets()
    {
      var xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
      xmlDoc2.Load("Packets.xml");

      foreach (XmlNode packet in xmlDoc2.DocumentElement)
       {
         var node = xmlDoc2.SelectSingleNode("pdml/packet/proto/field[@name='ip.src']/@show");                 
         ipsrc = node.Value;
         var node2 = xmlDoc2.SelectSingleNode("pdml/packet/proto/field[@name='ip.dst']/@show");
         string ipdst = node2.Value;
         list.Items.Add(ipsrc);
         list.Items.Add(ipdst);
       }
    }
```

This currently finds an IP source and destination but repeats the same one whilst adding it to the list box. There are different IP sources and destinations that are not being added.

Each packet looks like the following in the XML:

```
<packet>
<proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="54">
  <field name="num" pos="0" show="1" showname="Number" value="1" size="54"/>
  <field name="len" pos="0" show="54" showname="Frame Length" value="36" size="54"/>
  <field name="caplen" pos="0" show="54" showname="Captured Length" value="36" size="54"/>
  <field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Aug  4, 2014 14:18:24.053628000 GMT Daylight Time" showname="Captured Time" value="1407158304.053628000" size="54"/>
</proto>
<proto name="frame" showname="Frame 1: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0" size="54" pos="0">
  <field name="frame.interface_id" showname="Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{F1D229D2-3ADA-4820-85D2-FCE7FB5D24E5})" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
  <field name="frame.encap_type" showname="Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)" size="0" pos="0" show="1"/>
  <field name="frame.time" showname="Arrival Time: Aug  4, 2014 14:18:24.053628000 GMT Daylight Time" size="0" pos="0" show="&quot;Aug  4, 2014 14:18:24.053628000 GMT Daylight Time&quot;"/>
  <field name="frame.offset_shift" showname="Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000000000"/>
  <field name="frame.time_epoch" showname="Epoch Time: 1407158304.053628000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="1407158304.053628000"/>
  <field name="frame.time_delta" showname="Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000000000"/>
  <field name="frame.time_delta_displayed" showname="Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000000000"/>
  <field name="frame.time_relative" showname="Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds" size="0" pos="0" show="0.000000000"/>
  <field name="frame.number" showname="Frame Number: 1" size="0" pos="0" show="1"/>
  <field name="frame.len" showname="Frame Length: 54 bytes (432 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="54"/>
  <field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 54 bytes (432 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="54"/>
  <field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
  <field name="frame.ignored" showname="Frame is ignored: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
  <field name="frame.protocols" showname="Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp" size="0" pos="0" show="eth:ethertype:ip:tcp"/>
</proto>
<proto name="eth" showname="Ethernet II, Src: 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83 (78:e4:00:f9:ea:83), Dst: 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70 (98:8b:5d:b9:50:70)" size="14" pos="0">
  <field name="eth.dst" showname="Destination: 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70 (98:8b:5d:b9:50:70)" size="6" pos="0" show="98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" value="988b5db95070">
    <field name="eth.dst_resolved" showname="Destination (resolved): 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" hide="yes" size="6" pos="0" show="98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" value="988b5db95070"/>
    <field name="eth.addr" showname="Address: 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70 (98:8b:5d:b9:50:70)" size="6" pos="0" show="98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" value="988b5db95070"/>
    <field name="eth.addr_resolved" showname="Address (resolved): 98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" hide="yes" size="6" pos="0" show="98:8b:5d:b9:50:70" value="988b5db95070"/>
    <field name="eth.lg" showname=".... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)" size="3" pos="0" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="988b5d"/>
    <field name="eth.ig" showname=".... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)" size="3" pos="0" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="988b5d"/>
  </field>
  <field name="eth.src" showname="Source: 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83 (78:e4:00:f9:ea:83)" size="6" pos="6" show="78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" value="78e400f9ea83">
    <field name="eth.src_resolved" showname="Source (resolved): 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" hide="yes" size="6" pos="6" show="78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" value="78e400f9ea83"/>
    <field name="eth.addr" showname="Address: 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83 (78:e4:00:f9:ea:83)" size="6" pos="6" show="78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" value="78e400f9ea83"/>
    <field name="eth.addr_resolved" showname="Address (resolved): 78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" hide="yes" size="6" pos="6" show="78:e4:00:f9:ea:83" value="78e400f9ea83"/>
    <field name="eth.lg" showname=".... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)" size="3" pos="6" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="78e400"/>
    <field name="eth.ig" showname=".... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)" size="3" pos="6" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="78e400"/>
  </field>
  <field name="eth.type" showname="Type: IP (0x0800)" size="2" pos="12" show="2048" value="0800"/>
</proto>
<proto name="ip" showname="Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.204 (192.168.1.204), Dst: 162.159.242.165 (162.159.242.165)" size="20" pos="14">
  <field name="ip.version" showname="Version: 4" size="1" pos="14" show="4" value="45"/>
  <field name="ip.hdr_len" showname="Header Length: 20 bytes" size="1" pos="14" show="20" value="45"/>
  <field name="ip.dsfield" showname="Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))" size="1" pos="15" show="0" value="00">
    <field name="ip.dsfield.dscp" showname="0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)" size="1" pos="15" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="00"/>
    <field name="ip.dsfield.ecn" showname=".... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)" size="1" pos="15" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="00"/>
  </field>
  <field name="ip.len" showname="Total Length: 40" size="2" pos="16" show="40" value="0028"/>
  <field name="ip.id" showname="Identification: 0x1cf1 (7409)" size="2" pos="18" show="7409" value="1cf1"/>
  <field name="ip.flags" showname="Flags: 0x02 (Don&apos;t Fragment)" size="1" pos="20" show="2" value="40">
    <field name="ip.flags.rb" showname="0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set" size="1" pos="20" show="0" value="40"/>
    <field name="ip.flags.df" showname=".1.. .... = Don&apos;t fragment: Set" size="1" pos="20" show="1" value="40"/>
    <field name="ip.flags.mf" showname="..0. .... = More fragments: Not set" size="1" pos="20" show="0" value="40"/>
  </field>
  <field name="ip.frag_offset" showname="Fragment offset: 0" size="2" pos="20" show="0" value="4000"/>
  <field name="ip.ttl" showname="Time to live: 128" size="1" pos="22" show="128" value="80"/>
  <field name="ip.proto" showname="Protocol: TCP (6)" size="1" pos="23" show="6" value="06"/>
  <field name="ip.checksum" showname="Header checksum: 0x8625 [validation disabled]" size="2" pos="24" show="34341" value="8625">
    <field name="ip.checksum_good" showname="Good: False" size="2" pos="24" show="0" value="8625"/>
    <field name="ip.checksum_bad" showname="Bad: False" size="2" pos="24" show="0" value="8625"/>
  </field>
  <field name="ip.src" showname="Source: 192.168.1.204 (192.168.1.204)" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.204" value="c0a801cc"/>
  <field name="ip.addr" showname="Source or Destination Address: 192.168.1.204 (192.168.1.204)" hide="yes" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.204" value="c0a801cc"/>
  <field name="ip.src_host" showname="Source Host: 192.168.1.204" hide="yes" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.204" value="c0a801cc"/>
  <field name="ip.host" showname="Source or Destination Host: 192.168.1.204" hide="yes" size="4" pos="26" show="192.168.1.204" value="c0a801cc"/>
  <field name="ip.dst" showname="Destination: 162.159.242.165 (162.159.242.165)" size="4" pos="30" show="162.159.242.165" value="a29ff2a5"/>
  <field name="ip.addr" showname="Source or Destination Address: 162.159.242.165 (162.159.242.165)" hide="yes" size="4" pos="30" show="162.159.242.165" value="a29ff2a5"/>
  <field name="ip.dst_host" showname="Destination Host: 162.159.242.165" hide="yes" size="4" pos="30" show="162.159.242.165" value="a29ff2a5"/>
  <field name="ip.host" showname="Source or Destination Host: 162.159.242.165" hide="yes" size="4" pos="30" show="162.159.242.165" value="a29ff2a5"/>
  <field name="" show="Source GeoIP: Unknown" size="4" pos="26" value="c0a801cc"/>
  <field name="" show="Destination GeoIP: Unknown" size="4" pos="30" value="a29ff2a5"/>
</proto>
<proto name="tcp" showname="Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 6287 (6287), Dst Port: 443 (443), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0" size="20" pos="34">
  <field name="tcp.srcport" showname="Source Port: 6287 (6287)" size="2" pos="34" show="6287" value="188f"/>
  <field name="tcp.dstport" showname="Destination Port: 443 (443)" size="2" pos="36" show="443" value="01bb"/>
  <field name="tcp.port" showname="Source or Destination Port: 6287" hide="yes" size="2" pos="34" show="6287" value="188f"/>
  <field name="tcp.port" showname="Source or Destination Port: 443" hide="yes" size="2" pos="36" show="443" value="01bb"/>
  <field name="tcp.stream" showname="Stream index: 0" size="0" pos="34" show="0"/>
  <field name="tcp.len" showname="TCP Segment Len: 0" size="1" pos="46" show="0" value="50"/>
  <field name="tcp.seq" showname="Sequence number: 1    (relative sequence number)" size="4" pos="38" show="1" value="b99b3a34"/>
  <field name="tcp.ack" showname="Acknowledgment number: 1    (relative ack number)" size="4" pos="42" show="1" value="bd9a09d0"/>
  <field name="tcp.hdr_len" showname="Header Length: 20 bytes" size="1" pos="46" show="20" value="50"/>
  <field name="tcp.flags" showname=".... 0000 0001 0000 = Flags: 0x010 (ACK)" size="2" pos="46" show="16" value="10" unmaskedvalue="5010">
    <field name="tcp.flags.res" showname="000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set" size="1" pos="46" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="50"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.ns" showname="...0 .... .... = Nonce: Not set" size="1" pos="46" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="50"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.cwr" showname=".... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced (CWR): Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="10"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.ecn" showname=".... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="10"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.urg" showname=".... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="10"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.ack" showname=".... ...1 .... = Acknowledgment: Set" size="1" pos="47" show="1" value="1" unmaskedvalue="10"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.push" showname=".... .... 0... = Push: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="10"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.reset" showname=".... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="10"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.syn" showname=".... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="10"/>
    <field name="tcp.flags.fin" showname=".... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set" size="1" pos="47" show="0" value="0" unmaskedvalue="10"/>
  </field>
  <field name="tcp.window_size_value" showname="Window size value: 67" size="2" pos="48" show="67" value="0043"/>
  <field name="tcp.window_size" showname="Calculated window size: 67" size="2" pos="48" show="67" value="0043"/>
  <field name="tcp.window_size_scalefactor" showname="Window size scaling factor: -1 (unknown)" size="2" pos="48" show="-1" value="0043"/>
  <field name="tcp.checksum" showname="Checksum: 0x8253 [validation disabled]" size="2" pos="50" show="33363" value="8253">
    <field name="tcp.checksum_good" showname="Good Checksum: False" size="2" pos="50" show="0" value="8253"/>
    <field name="tcp.checksum_bad" showname="Bad Checksum: False" size="2" pos="50" show="0" value="8253"/>
  </field>
  <field name="tcp.urgent_pointer" showname="Urgent pointer: 0" size="2" pos="52" show="0" value="0000"/>
</proto>
 </packet>
```

I know it's very long but that is the format it comes in. What would be the best way to make the IP source a unique identifier, whilst adding the IP destinations to a list. It needs to be able to do this for every packet in the file.

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: I accidentally submitted before adding the bulk of the question.

Answer (score 1):

i think @name of the <field> is unique across all the packets so that i apply following xpath

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc2.DocumentElement;
var results = node.SelectNodes("//field[@name='ip.src']");
foreach (XmlNode result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Attributes["show"].Value); 
}
```

--SJ